# How To Modify Show UI of a Registered Taxonomy On Demand

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

As you you know the `'show_ui'` Boolean option in taking care of rendering or not rending the Taxonomy Menu on UI on registering  ataxonomy.
function custom_taxonomy() {

```
$labels = array(
    'name'                       => 'Taxonomies',
    'singular_name'              => 'Taxonomy',
    'menu_name'                  => 'Taxonomy',
    'all_items'                  => 'All Items',
    'parent_item'                => 'Parent Item',
    'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Item:',
    'new_item_name'              => 'New Item Name',
    'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Item',
    'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Item',
    'update_item'                => 'Update Item',
    'view_item'                  => 'View Item',
    'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate items with commas',
    'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove items',
    'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used',
    'popular_items'              => 'Popular Items',
    'search_items'               => 'Search Items',
    'not_found'                  => 'Not Found',
    'no_terms'                   => 'No items',
    'items_list'                 => 'Items list',
    'items_list_navigation'      => 'Items list navigation',
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => false,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
);
register_taxonomy( 'taxonomy', array( 'post' ), $args );

   }
   add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy', 0 );
```

Is there any way to modify this option after registering the taxonomy? like any hook or filter to toggle the Boolean in `functions.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `register_taxonomy_args` to filter the taxonomy options *before* the taxonomy is registered, or while it's being registered.

Example code:

```
/*
 * @param array $args The taxonomy args such as show_ui.
 * @param string $taxonomy The taxonomy name.
 */
add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_args', function ( $args, $taxonomy ) {
    if ( 'my_taxonomy' === $taxonomy ) {
        $args['show_ui'] = false;
    }

    return $args;
}, 10, 2 );
```

There is also an "action" you can "hook" into, where this filter is fired just *after* a taxonomy is registered. Here, you can, for example, assign other post/object type(s) to the taxonomy.

Example code:

```
/*
 * @param string $taxonomy The taxonomy name.
 */
add_action( 'registered_taxonomy', function ( $taxonomy ) {
    if ( 'my_taxonomy' === $taxonomy ) {
        register_taxonomy_for_object_type( $taxonomy, 'post' );
    }
} );
```

And if you must (or need to) modify the `show_ui` (or any other options) of a taxonomy *after* it's registered, then you can use the global `$wp_taxonomies`, which is an `array` of all registered taxonomies.

Example code:

```
/*
 * @param string $taxonomy The taxonomy name.
 */
add_action( 'registered_taxonomy', function ( $taxonomy ) {
    if ( 'my_taxonomy' === $taxonomy ) {
        global $wp_taxonomies;

        if ( ! is_array( $wp_taxonomies )
        || ! isset( $wp_taxonomies[ $taxonomy ] ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $wp_taxonomies[ $taxonomy ]->show_ui = false;
    }
} );
```